# Is it safe to move a mutex in Swift?

Tags: swift, concurrency, pthreads

I was doing some research on mutexes and came across the following Swift code:

```
class Lock {

    private var mutex: pthread_mutex_t = {
        var mutex = pthread_mutex_t()
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, nil)
        return mutex
    }()

    func someFunc() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)
        defer { pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex) }
        ...
    }

}
```

The code defines and initializes a pthread_mutex_t within the closure, then assigns the returned value to a class property. It then lock and unlocks within several of the functions as shown.

Since one should also call pthread_mutex_destroy, it implies that some sort of allocation is occurring within the mutex which may or may not reference the address of the original value.

In effect, the mutex is initialized in one place and stored in another.

The question is whether or not it's safe or correct to do this?

What if the mutex initializer needed arguments?

```
    private var mutex: pthread_mutex_t = {
        var recursiveMutex = pthread_mutex_t()
        var recursiveMutexAttr = pthread_mutexattr_t()
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&recursiveMutexAttr)
        pthread_mutexattr_settype(&recursiveMutexAttr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE)
        pthread_mutex_init(&recursiveMutex, &recursiveMutexAttr)
        return recursiveMutex
     }()
```

The later strikes me as definitely being incorrect, as the attribute storage whose address is passed into the mutex will disappear when the closure collapses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not, this code is broken.

To work, the `pthread_mutex_t` would need to be initialized in-place within a class instance, and *never* copied out. The class would need to expose lock/unlock methods which operator on the instance-variable in-place.

> #### Value Types
>
> Note that `pthread_mutex_t`, `pthread_rwlock_t`, and `os_unfair_lock` are value types, not reference types. That means that if you use = on them, you make a copy. This is important, because these types can't be copied! If you copy one of the pthread types, the copy will be unusable and may crash when you try to use it.

– [By Mike Ash, Friday Q&A 2017-10-27: Locks, Thread Safety, and Swift: 2017 Edition](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-10-27-locks-thread-safety-and-swift-2017-edition.html)

Check out https://cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/06/02/threads-and-mutexes.html

And this example usage of `pthread_mutex_t` in Swift: https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlUtils/blob/0bfc4587d01cfc796b6c7e118fc631333dd8ab33/Sources/CwlUtils/CwlMutex.swift#L60-L105

Comment: I am genuinely curious how this doesn't violate the notion that swift is strongly typed.  A simple operation (copy) resulting in the formation of an effectively useless object doesn't seem substantively different from the sorts of type errors enabled by languages like C.

Comment: Type safety is only one (albiet very useful, and common) dimension of program safety. There's no shortage of ways to foot-gun yourself, particularly if threading is involved. If it's any consolation, move-only data types are being developed, and this is one of their possible applications. Though really, IMO, apple should have just provided correct/safe wrappers around `pthread_mutex_t`, and hid it from Swift entirely (IIRC, `NSLock` is exactly this).

Comment: Wouldn't move only then invalidate the original in a copy?   Like I had an object Q that contained a mutex, and I made a copy P; now P's mutex controls Q, and Q's is random?  Maybe I should over whatever version swift has moved to in the last three years.

Comment: "Wouldn't move only then invalidate the original in a copy?" As far as I understand it, yes. The difference is that if this was a language supported feature, the compiler could enforce that accesses to the old location can't be done, in any way.

Comment: For example, take a look at [`UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T>.withMemoryRebound(to:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablebufferpointer/2949522-withmemoryrebound). It does a move in a sense, but there's no compiler enforcement: "Because this buffer’s memory is no longer bound to its Element type while the body closure executes, do not access memory using the original buffer from within body." You *can* still access the original buffer. It's UB, but nothing can stop you until the compiler knows about move-only types.

Comment: Interesting; thanks.  This one will probably generate the "take it private thing" :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227130/discussion-between-alexander-and-mevets).